# Do GUI and Terminal execution (of Back In Time/Grsync/other Linux apps) produce the same results?

Tags: linux, terminal, rsync

I've opened [Back In Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/) GUI and copied the whole `rsync ...` line from the last log into Terminal and executed it in Terminal.

Question #1 is: if I were to do it the normal way (click 'Take snapshot' in Back In Time GUI) would it do **exactly** the same thing? Or does Back In Time GUI add some actions or tweak something while executing that `rsync` command?

Also, the same question (Question #2) but about [Grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/).

And about the Linux apps in general (if that can be answered) (Question #3).

I'm asking the first two questions because backups are a serious business and before moving them into the shell (perhaps even for cron/anacron jobs) I want to be sure that backups procedure will not change.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding your Question #1:**

Yes and No. The command will do exactly the same like in BIT GUI. But BIT will do couple thinks before and after running this command (create 'new_snapshot' dir, fix permissions, create hard-links, save permissions into extra file, save config and log, just to name some)

So in the end you'll not have the same result with running the `rsync` command manually as with BIT GUI.

disclaimer: I'm member of BIT-dev Team

Comment: Now I see that BIT GUI behaviour can't be substituted by launching `rsync` command from the log in the Terminal.
However, can I use GUI to configure a BIT profile to my liking and then launch this backup job from the Terminal without needing to launch GUI ever again? (Question #4)
Thanks for your answer and for developing BIT - the best backup app I've encountered.

Comment: Sure. You can always take a new snapshot by running `backintime --backup`. You can also create a schedule which will run without GUI (take a look at `crontab -l`). Since version 1.0.26 you can restore from command line, too. And there is a new manpage for the config file in `man backintime-config`

Comment: Thank you. True, and it's all in the `man` page (I'm only just starting to move from GUI into the shell, so I haven't checked `man` before). Just to add, the precise command I was looking for was:
`backintime --profile PROFILE\ NAME --backup`